# Sitecore Remote Publishing Cache Issue

Tags: caching, sitecore

I have an AUTHORING machine, a FAILOVER machine, and a PUBLIC machine. AUTHORING points to both FAILOVER and PUBLIC as remote publishing targets.

When publishing to all targets the content is immediately visible on FAILOVER. However, I am forced to manually clear the cache on PUBLIC to have the new content viewable by visitors.

I'm hopeful this is a simple configuration issue that someone can point me to an answer for.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Probably, the cache clearing configuration is different on FAILOVER and PUBLIC. It's difficult to say exactly based on the info you provided, but the links below might help you or give a hint:

- [Problem with publishing items and not seeing it until hours later](http://sdn.sitecore.net/SDN5/Forum/ShowPost.aspx?PostID=23661)
- [Clear Cache on Publish](http://sdn.sitecore.net/SDN5/Forum/ShowPost.aspx?PostID=31853)
- [Clear cache on publishing target - without staging module](http://sdn.sitecore.net/SDN5/Forum/ShowPost.aspx?PostID=8801)

Comment: In support of Yan's answer, it's probably worth doing a diff on the web.config of the failover and public servers.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of Failover and Public why not have the single Web database with the two servers sharing it? With a load balancer in front you'd not only have redundancy but also increased performance.

Comment: I like this idea too, it makes a redundancy with the app server but no the DB. You can maybe create a dark server for a failover DB.

Comment: But this wouldn't solve the original problem, would it?  Caching occurs on the web server.

Answer (score 0):

You might need to check your config to see if the history engine is setup/configured. E.g.

```xml
<sitecore><configuration>... 
<database id="webtarget"> 
... 
  <Engines.HistoryEngine.Storage> 
    <obj type="Sitecore.Data.$(database).$(database)HistoryStorage, Sitecore.Kernel"> 
      <param connectionStringName="$(id)" /> 
      <EntryLifeTime>30.00:00:00</EntryLifeTime> 
    </obj> 
  </Engines.HistoryEngine.Storage> 
</database> 
... 
<hooks> 
  <hook type="Sitecore.Modules.Staging.InitializeEngines, Staging.Kernel" /> 
</hooks> 
...
</configuration></sitecore>
```

Review the [staging module documentation](http://sdn.sitecore.net/Products/Staging/Documentation%20SC6.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Check the staging module logs to make sure the cache clear is successful on both servers following a publish. They can be found at:

\sitecore modules\staging\workdir

Perhaps there is a network or security error that is preventing the cache clear from working properly on PUBLIC?